# Got @angular/* version ~9.0.0-next-0 when tried to upgrade to Angular Material 8 via ng update. Why this discrepancy?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-material-8

I am trying to upgrade an Angular 7 application to Angular 8 using instructions from [here](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0). Everything went well until the last step:

> ng update @angular/material

This updated Angular Material packages to 8.1.2, but also upgraded @angular/* packages to a rather strange an undesired version: ~9.0.0-next.0

[image: Angular Material 7 -> 8 upgrade effect]

This is problematic (I had to get rid of a non-essential dev dependency that requires Angular <= 8) as I do not want to go beyond [version 8 which is the latest stable one](https://angular.io/guide/releases).

How should I tackle this?

Comment: This has been an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14980) with the CLI for a little while now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that before running a `ng update @angular/material` some of your dependencies were already on `8.2.0` while `@angular/material` was still on version 7.

`ng update @angular/material` apparently only checks if there is update available for `@angular/material` - not for other dependencies that it might update on the way. So when you launched the command, it noticed that there was a newer version available and it proceeded with updating. Other dependencies got updated as well as they were on a version 8 before doing an update (and there was version 9 available).

This is why you always have to keep an eye that all your versions are aligned before doing an update.

And just a small observation: The `9.0.0-next.0` was released just an hour before you did the update. So if you did it before that, you wouldn't have any of these problems.

The possible fix for this is to manually edit the `package.json` and change the dependencies with version `^9.0.0-next.0` to `^8.2.0`

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I am very new to `ng update` and it really helped understand how it works.

Comment: Don't we run into the risk that ´ng update´ applies changes coming with Version 9.X, which don't applie for Version 8.X?

Answer (score 2):

The community seems to think this is a bug.  See:  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14980 (scroll down).